# Representable map of Deligne-Mumford stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

Let $\mathscr{M}\to\mathscr{N}$ be a map of (Deligne-Mumford) stacks. Recall that it is said to be representable by affine schemes if for all affine maps $\operatorname{Spec}R\to \mathscr{N}$, the pullback $\mathscr{M}\times_\mathscr{N}\operatorname{Spec}R$ is equivalent to an affine scheme.

What is a criterion for when a map of the associated Hopf algebroids which induces a map of DM-stacks $\mathscr{M}\to\mathscr{N}$ which is representable by affine schemes? (What about the analogous question for flat maps of stacks?)

I know that if $(L,W)$ is the Hopf algebroid asociated to $\mathscr{M}$ and $\mathscr{N}$, respectively, then it suffices to check the representability of $\mathscr{M}\to\mathscr{N}(L,W)$ on the morphism $\operatorname{Spec}L\to\mathscr{N}$. Is there a similar statement for the map $\mathscr{M}\to \mathscr{N}$ if $(A,\Gamma)$ is the Hopf algebroid asociated to $\mathscr{M}$?

Comment: I believe that the usual definition of "representable" is that $\mathcal{M}\times_{\mathcal{N}}\text{Spec}\ R$ is a scheme (some authors allow an algebraic space).  What you wrote is usually called "representable by affine schemes" or "representable by affine morphisms".

Comment: @JasonStarr Ah, I didn't know that. I'll edit the question accordingly; I'm interested in the case when the map of stacks is representable by affine schemes, although I'd be interested in learning about the general case as well!

Comment: one can apply Artin representability (see, for example, the intro http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/DAG-XIV.pdf) to $M \times_N Spec\,\mathbb{Z}$ to see if it is representable by an algebraic space. Then you are asking when is an algebraic space an affine scheme in which case you have Serre's affineness criterion: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07V6.

Comment: @EldenElmanto I'm not too familiar with the algebro-geometric stuff, but is it possible to express $\mathscr{M}\times_\mathscr{N}\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf{Z}$ as a DM-stack associated to a Hopf algebroid? (Because quasicoherent sheaves over a DM-stack $\mathscr{M}(A,\Gamma)$ are equivalent to $(A,\Gamma)$-modules this will be a "criterion on the Hopf algebroid".) Also, is there a Hopf algebroid-al analogue of Artin representability?

Comment: Re the first question my comment above: it's possible to express $\mathscr{M}\times_\mathscr{N}\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf{Z}$ as a DM-stack associated to a Hopf algebroid via tensor products of Hopf algebroids. The Serre affineness criterion translates into asking that Ext of the tensor product of the Hopf algebroids should be acyclic.

Comment: @SanathK.Devalapurkar maybe you could add a reference to DM stacks coming from Hopf algebroids?

Comment: @MattiaTalpo Sure. If $(A,\Gamma)$ is a Hopf algebroid, we can take Spec to get $(\mathrm{Spec}(A),\mathrm{Spec}(\Gamma))$. This is a groupoid scheme. The stack associated to the groupoid scheme $[\mathrm{Spec}(\Gamma)\rightrightarrows\mathrm{Spec}(A)]$ is the DM stack coming from the Hopf algebroid $(A,\Gamma)$.

Comment: @SanathK.Devalapurkar thanks. And what's a Hopf algebroid exactly? (I actually meant a reference as in 'somewhere to look'...)

Comment: @MattiaTalpo My apologies. I learnt about Hopf algebroids from Appendix A.1 of Ravenel's Green book, available here: http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/mybooks/ravenelA1.pdf. A short and brief summary is in Appendix B.3 of Ravenel's Orange book; I believe he has a PDF of the book on his webpage.

Comment: (Also, Naumann's preprint arXiv:math/0503308 [math.AT] is a good reference.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you mean representable *by affine schemes*, on usual schemes this is called an *affine* map. This is an important class of maps but quite restrictive, too. The question you ask is the main concern of the paper

> Powell, Geoffrey M. L. On affine morphisms of Hopf algebroids.
>   Homology, Homotopy Appl. 10 (2008), no. 1, 53–95.

The result you ask for is Theorem 1.2. on page 55. Unfortunately it is too long to reproduce it here. I hope this answers your question.